# What are this components on uBlox EVA M8M GPS?

Tags: microcontroller, schematics, gps, gnss

I am designing my own pcb board based on a [Sodaq One V3](https://support.sodaq.com/Boards/One/SODAQ_ONE_v3.pdf) (I built my prototype with a Sodaq One V3 and a MAX30102) and I am currently integrating both devices in KiCAD but I have a doubt with the GPS components.
The official page says the GPS is an uBlox EVA M8M and I already have the symbol and footprint, but I have doubt with the *1575.42 Mhz SAW filter U3 Component* (could I use this one? [B39162B9416K610](https://www.mouser.mx/ProductDetail/RF360/B39162B9416K610?qs=AKDv8POSxR2wZTu%252B%2FrDYjA%3D%3D)), the schematic GPS circuit schematic is:
[image: GPS Circuit]

And the other doubt is about U4 component, I have no idea what that component is, I also tried to see other Sodaq boards schematics but no success since other boards do not have GPS module.
Could somebody help me please?
[image: U4 Component of gps circuit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [EVA-8M Hardware Integration Guide](https://content.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/EVA-8M-M8-FW3_HIM_%28UBX-16010593%29.pdf) makes the following suggestions for the SAW filter:

| Manufacturer | Order no. | System supported | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TDK/ EPCOS | B8401: B39162B8401P810 | GPS+GLONASS | High attenuation |
| TDK/ EPCOS | B3913: B39162B3913U410 | GPS+GLONASS+BeiDou | For automotive application |
| TDK/ EPCOS | B9416: B39162B9416K610 | GPS | High input power |
| TDK/ EPCOS | B4310: B39162B4310P810 | GPS+GLONASS | Compliant to the AEC-Q200 standard |
| TDK/ EPCOS | B4327: B39162B4327P810 | GPS+GLONASS+BeiDou | Low insertion loss |
| TDK/ EPCOS | B9482: B39162B9482P810 | GPS+GLONASS | Low insertion loss |
| Murata | SAFFB1G56KB0F0A | GPS+GLONASS+BeiDou | Low insertion loss, only for mobile application |
| Murata | SAFEA1G58KA0F00 | GPS+GLONASS | Only for mobile application |
| Murata | SAFFB1G58KA0F0A | GPS+GLONASS | Only for mobile application |
| Triquint | 856561 | GPS | Compliant to the AEC-Q200 standard |
| TAI-SAW | TA1573A | GPS+GLONASS | Low insertion loss |
| TAI-SAW | TA1343A | GPS+GLONASS+BeiDou | Low insertion loss |

The hardware integration guide also has a lot of other good-to-read information both regarding the SAW filter and everything else.

Regarding U4, it's probably a high side load switch of some model. Only needed if you need to turn the GPS receiver on and off.

Comment: thank you so much, I will read more about what you shared!!!